# Visiting Australia - Can I go for a week, leave for two weeks, and come back for two months?

Tags: visas, australia, canadian-citizens, multiple-entry

My understanding is that I can visit Australia for three months with a basic travel visa. One issue is that I plan on visiting New Zealand for two weeks after I visit Sydney for a week. I plan on returning to Australia for another two months. Can I do this?

Also, what happens when you leave Australia and come back? Do I need two visas? If I go for a month, leave for a month, can I come back for 2 months? In other words, does time "in" Australia still accumulate if you leave the country for a bit?

Comment: Canadian. I don't have a visa, I suppose this would work if I got multiple entry?

Comment: I believe Canadians don't need a visa for Australia, I'm assuming for up to 90 days, and should be the same for NZ. So it's trivial for you!

Comment: @hippietrail not if the 90 day limit continues while he's out the country, which is what I believe he's asking - ie does it reset if he border hops.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Ah yes I only saw the first part of the question where he was talking about one or two weeks in each country and didn't notice that later he asks about one or two months in each country.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a definitive answer, but still might help.

As a Canadian, you will need to get an ETA to visit Australia -

> All travellers, except New Zealand citizens, must obtain a visa or travel authority before travelling to Australia.

http://www.canada.embassy.gov.au/otwa/visiting_australia.html

More information on the ETA is available here - http://www.immi.gov.au/visas/visitor/601/

> Your ETA is valid for 12 months. You can enter and stay in Australia for up to three months at a time. If your passport expires before your ETA, you will need to reapply.

...

> Your ETA lets you enter Australia for up to three months at a time as a tourist or for business.

...

> You must comply with all ETA conditions and Australian laws. You cannot stay in Australia for longer than three months on each visit.

Nothing there seems to suggest that your visa does *not* reset when you leave the country, so a trip to NZ may suffice in allowing you to stay for 3 months in Australia on return from NZ.

There's some anecdotal evidence of this being allowed here (http://yanksdownunder.net/topic/8794417/1/) but I wouldn't bet on it.

I know the US doesn't look too kindly on this kind of behaviour for Australians though (i.e. Australian ESTA holders visiting Canada and returning to the US hoping for a visa reset).

I'd ask your local Australian embassy just to be on the safe side - http://www.immi.gov.au/contacts/visa-enquiries/eta.htm

Comment: Fun fact, Kiwis do need a visa if we arrive in Australia by boat! :)

Comment: Yes the US has specific rules that your visa doesn't reset when you go to Canada, and I think also Mexico. I believe I heard recently that they wanted to extend this to Central America as well.